# iPad 1 not detecting LESS css?

Tags: css, less

While debugging our website I found a bug with an iPad viewing in portrait mode. As we are using bootstrap I applied the LESS CSS technique but it looks like Safari isn't compatible with this. Am I correct that iOS 5.1.1 doesn't support less with less.js?

EDIT: Adding some code what I'm doing:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="/less/bootstrap.less" />  
<script src="/js/less-1.5.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<!-- SKIN --> 
<link href="/css/new_style.css" rel="stylesheet"></script>
```

Also, I'm testing on an iPad 1 (iOS5.1.1) and 2 (iOS 7). iPad 2 works like a charm.

Comment: I always find that when I have questions about support or bugs, I check the issues section of the github repo:

https://github.com/less/less.js/issues

Are you using less on the fly in production or are you compiling it before pushing it live?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok: It seems less.js isn't compatible with iPad 1. As Hiral said, better use CSS.

How to get this working:

1) Download the source from getbootstrap
2) Download a LESS application (like [less app for MAC](http://incident57.com/less/))
3) Open less.app and setup stuff.

Open the variables.less file and change the following:

@grid-float-breakpoint:     **@screen-md-min;**

When you save the variables.less the file bootstrap.css will be added as well. Replace this file with your current and everything works like a charm again.

Answer (score 5):

It is always better practice to compile `LESS` file and place `css` code instead of directly placing `LESS` file.

Comment: +1. rwzdoorn, you can also look into the compiling section of the github repo: https://github.com/less/less.js/#usage and if you're not comfortable with the command line, look into the gui compilers that use less: https://github.com/less/less.js/wiki/GUI-compilers-that-use-LESS.js

Comment: Hi Hiral, thanks for your comment. I'm not familiar with LESS but I think it's strange I can't find any info what's going wrong on the iPad 1. When viewing with iPad 2 (iOS7) it works like a charm.